# Reversing singly linked list, recursively

Tags: list, recursion, linked-list

So, I have as part of my lesson in Computer Programming to reverse a singly linked list of nodes, based on this algorithm

> "Traversing the list sequentially, remove each node and insert it as the new first node."

I was able to do this iteratively, but now my professor wants us to do this recursively.
I am trying my best to understand recursion, but its not working very well.

So, I changed my coding from iteratively to what I believe to be recursively

```
private void recursiveReverse2(Node p)
{
    Node lead = p;
    Node tail = p;

    if (p == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (p.next == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    current = tail.next;
    lead = current.next;
    current.next = null;
    tail.next = lead;
    current.next = head;
    head = current;
    recursiveReverse2(tail);
}


public void reverse2()
{
    toggle();   //swithces sort of list from ascending-descending
    recursiveReverse2(head); //head initialized at start of class
}
```

Basically, I wanted to ask if what I have done actually *is* recursion. Because, the recursiveReverse2() *does* work, but I just don't know if I have implemented recursion or not.

Comment: Calling a function from within itself with the use of recursive cases and base cases. Looks proper to me.

Comment: Recursion means that the method that does work calls itself.

Comment: Recursion doesn't help much in your example. In Java, recursion is more useful if there are multiple recursive calls in same method, like in a mergesort implementation.

Comment: I guess you could use tail recursion, but it would be a highly artificial approach to the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the comments - if MAD2492's professor want to use this as a vehicle to teach recursion then that is reason enough to try to write a recursive version of the algorithm. When to choose recursion over iteration in the real world is a different (still interesting, but different) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing recursion, it's usually best to think about the end case(s), then write the recursive case last.  The other thing about recursion is its extremely useful to return the result.

Yes, your solution is technically recursive, but I don't think the code works.  At the line `current.next = head`, head is not defined, unless this code is in some class that you've not shown.  Worse yet, it may infinite loop, because at the beginning of the function, `tail = p` and at the end your recursion is called with `tail`, thus an infinite loop. At best this will reverse a list of length 3, but not a list of any length.

In Java, the recursive function often needs a "helper" function to get it started.  First, assume the following node class:

```
public class Node{
    public object data;
    public Node next;
}
```

And given the problem statement, I'm assuming we're not allowed to play with the data pointers, just the next pointers.  This code would be some other class than Node.

```
public Node recursiveReverse(Node p)
{
    return helperReverse(p, null);
} 

private Node helperReverse(Node p, Node previous)
{
    if (p == null)
    {
        return p;
    }
    else if (p.next == null)
    {
        p.next == previous;
        return p;
    }
    else
    {
        Node next = p.next;
        p.next = previous;
        return helperReverse(next, p);
    }
}
```

It gets even better if it's incorporated in the Node class.

```
public class Node{
    public object data;
    public Node next;

    public Node reverse() {
        return reverse1(null);
    } 

    private Node reverse1(Node previous) {
        if (next == null) {
            next == previous;
            return this;
        }
        else {
            Node other = next;
            next = previous;
            return reverse1(other, this);
        } 
    }

}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

RECURSIVE CODE IN C++ assuming you have a node class which has a next pointer....
two functions first to call the recursive function and second recursive function to reverse the singly linked list

```
 void callReverse()
 {
  node *tempPointer=head;
  head=NULL;
  reverse(tempPointer);
 }
```

second function is the recursive function

```
 void reverse(node * pointer)
 {

  if(pointer->next==NULL)   //this case works only when linked list has a single node
  {
    if(head==NULL)
     head=pointer; 
  }

  else if(pointer->next->next!=NULL)
  {
    reverse(pointer->next)  //recursive call
  }

  if(head==NULL)
   head=pointer->next;

  pointer->next->next=pointer;

  pointer->next=NULL;

 }
```

do give me your suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
void driver(Node head)
{
    rec_rev_ll(head,NULL); 
}

void rec_rev_ll(Node head, Node prev) 
{
    Node tmp = head->next;
    if(tmp == NULL) // Ends recursion when end of linked list is reached.
    {
        head->next = prev;
        return;
    }
    head->next = prev;
    rec_rev_ll(tmp,head);
}
```

Short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the list without using any temporary node:

```
struct node* reverse_helper(struct node *ptr, struct node **head)
{
        if(ptr->next == NULL)
            *head = ptr;
        else 
            (reverse(ptr->next,head))->next = ptr;

        return ptr;
}        

/*Call reverseList Function with your List head reference */
void reverseList(struct node **head)
{
     struct node *ptr = reverse_helper(*head,head);
     ptr->next = NULL;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`void recursiveReverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
    struct node* first;
    struct node* rest;`

```
/* empty list */
if (*head_ref == NULL)
   return;  

/* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
first = *head_ref; 
rest  = first->next;

/* List has only one node */
if (rest == NULL)
   return;  

/* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
recursiveReverse(&rest);
first->next->next  = first; 

/* tricky step -- see the diagram */
first->next  = NULL;         

/* fix the head pointer */
*head_ref = rest;
```

`}`

Explanation

Here pointer first and next are local for each interanl call. On the stackeach time function call itself the two temporary pointers created on stack now *first is the front element for the link list while *rest is the pointer to next element on linked list. In each call net is passed to the recursion means the second elements pointer is passesd. At the end when no element left  if `(rest == NULL)` stack unwinding starts in the stack unwnding occurs. In stack unwnding *rest forward will point to the low level *first pointer this simply reverse the pointer from one stack to other during unwinding. At the initial *first becomes the last elemnt so its next is changed to null to prevent illegal referene `first->next  = NULL`

Comment: Fix your indent and explain your code to be more educative.